# Why does this python code crash my website? And this other python code does not?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Why does the first code below crash my website while the second doesn't?

Here is the code that crashes the website:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls'))
]
```

And here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "learning_log/learning_log/urls.py", line 17, in <module>  from django.contrib import admin
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Here is the code that does not crash:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I'm using python 3 and django 2.

Comment: Please, show the traceback.

Comment: what does the traceback mean?  it has been added to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose the include learning locgs are in the format mysite/posts/the_restof_learning_urls, you have to do  `url(r'^posts/', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='posts')),`

So you have (path('',) which is an empty string there, and has to add the urls for learning.

After that, you have to customize your posts/learning.urls--->

```
    from posts.views import 
(posts_list,posts_create,posts_delete,posts_detail,posts_update)
from posts import views as posts_views

app_name= 'posts'    
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$',posts_views.posts_list, name='list'),
        url(r'^create/$', posts_views.posts_create),
        url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', posts_views.posts_detail, name='detail'),
        # url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'), #Django Code Review #3 on joincfe.com/youtube/
        url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', posts_views.posts_update, name='update'),
        url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', posts_views.posts_delete),
        #url(r'^posts/$', "<appname>.views.<function_name>"),

]
```

You have to customise it as per your own code, by changing posts with your learning app

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show how to solve the problem using path( ) instead of url( )?   Thank you

Comment: instead of url use path is the same thing.